# Как вставить команду изменения цвета ячейки одновременно с командой изменения значения?

Tags: python, flask, google-spreadsheet

Этот код у меня работает и отвечает за отправку данных в таблицу

```
value_range_body = {"values": [[time, num, ads, res]]}  # Insert data
request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                                                 range=range_,
                                                 valueInputOption=value_input_option,
                                                 insertDataOption=insert_data_option,
                                                 body=value_range_body)
response = request.execute()
return print('Результат сохранения в таблицу гугл:'), response
```

Нужно реализовать возможность одновременно с добавлением данных изменять цвет ячеек. Возможно ли вставить соответствующий код в "value_range_body"?
Если да, то каким синтаксисом это реализуется?
Используется Flask, Python.
Пробовал просто для теста использовать команду изменения цвета таким образом:

```
    value_range_body = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": 0,
          "endRowIndex": 1
        },
        "cell": {
          "userEnteredFormat": {
            "backgroundColor": {
              "red": 0.0,
              "green": 0.0,
              "blue": 0.0
            },
            "horizontalAlignment" : "CENTER",
            "textFormat": {
              "foregroundColor": {
                "red": 1.0,
                "green": 1.0,
                "blue": 1.0
              },
              "fontSize": 12,
              "bold": true
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment)"
      }
    },
    {
      "updateSheetProperties": {
        "properties": {
          "sheetId": spreadsheet_id,
          "gridProperties": {
            "frozenRowCount": 1
          }
        },
        "fields": "gridProperties.frozenRowCount"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Результата не дало.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, нельзя сделать `batch`, чтобы сразу добавить (`append`) и покрасить ячейки. В основном это зависит от специфики самого метода `append`. Например, вы можете попробовать сделать работу за него, но у вас все равно получится 2 запроса: поиск последней строки и обновление данных.

Вы не учли или совершили опечатку в

- `"sheetId": spreadsheet_id,`
- `"bold": true`
- `spreadsheets().batchUpdate()` не принимает `data`, он работает с `repeatCell`, поэтому данные можно добавить через `userEnteredValue`.

---

```
requests = [{
    "repeatCell": {
        "range": {
            "sheetId": sheetId,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 1
        },
        "cell": {
            "userEnteredValue":{
                "stringValue": 'string'
            },
            "userEnteredFormat": {
                "backgroundColor": {
                    "red": 0.0,
                    "green": 0.0,
                    "blue": 0.0
                },
                "horizontalAlignment": "CENTER",
                "textFormat": {
                    "foregroundColor": {
                        "red": 1.0,
                        "green": 1.0,
                        "blue": 1.0
                    },
                    "fontSize": 12,
                    "bold": True
                }
            }
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment)"
    }
}, {
    "updateSheetProperties": {
        "properties": {
            "sheetId": sheetId,
            "gridProperties": {
                "frozenRowCount": 1
            }
        },
        "fields": "gridProperties.frozenRowCount"
    }
}];

body = {
    'requests': requests
}

response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
    spreadsheetId = spreadsheetId,
    body = body).execute()
```

### Ссылки

- [Formatting cells with the Google Sheets API (The G Suite Dev Show)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86q5TMzvRqo)
- [spreadsheets/request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request)
- [Генерируем красивую Google-таблицу из своей программы (используя Google Sheets API v4)](https://habr.com/ru/post/305378/)
- [Пример для тестирования](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DP-skJNY48pVVvBvgB_XruvG4ZywJSOj)

Comment: Спасибо, но все же хочется узнать ответ на главный вопрос: возможно ли реализовать добавление данных в первую свободную строку и обработку форматированием этой же строки? То есть ваш ответ говорит как правильно форматировать конкретные строки, но как форматировать строку, координаты которой неизвестны? Например данные всегда добавляются поочередно при каждом запросе построчно. Как реализовать окрашивание строк в зависимости от аргументов этого запроса или любых других параметров по отношению к новым данным?

Comment: @АликсПлисов, обновил. Постарайтесь формулировать вопрос более точно.